# Remove a attribute(hidden) in a html with a function

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a question for you i will remove a attribute (Hidden) whit a Input type button can you help me 
this is my script

tanks for your help

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="Test">
<hr>
<button id="ici" hidden="">lol</button>

<script>
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById("ici").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
</script>
```

Comment: Do I understand correctly, by default button is hidden, and it should be visible when you click on the button?

Comment: What do you mean with "whit"?

Comment: document.getElementById("ici").hidden = false;

Comment: Finaly all its ok, in my direct view in Dreamweaver this doesn't work but in website that work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what's not working?

```js
function myfunction() {
  document.getElementById("ici").removeAttribute("hidden");
}
```

```html
<input type="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="Test">
<hr>
<button id="ici" hidden=''>lol</button>
```

Comment: For it to work I must put the function before my code if I understand correctly ??

Comment: sorry on my direct view i did see this work :) tanks for the help

Comment: that's one way. please accept answer if it works for you.